# How to pass Level 6 "function doInigo" in vim-adventures?

Tags: vim-adventures

### Problem

In [vim-adventures](http://vim-adventures.com/), I've almost finished level 6 but I didn't find how to resolve the puzzle *function doInigo()*. I tried this maybe 100 times and for the moment I miss it for one keystroke.

[image: vim-adventures level 6]

### My current moves

I start on the line with the text "what's up" and then have 25 keystrokes to do the job.

- (1) <kbd>E</kbd> to move to the "!",
- (2) <kbd>l</kbd> to go to the blank character
- (3) <kbd>D</kbd> to delete the end of the line
- (4-6) <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> to be on the line "Mrs." on the "I" of  Inigo. For the moment I don't have the right to use <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.
- (7) <kbd>B</kbd> to be at the begining of the word "Mrs. "
- (8-9) <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to delete the word "Mrs. "
- (10) <kbd>j</kbd> to go the the next line
- (11-12) <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete the line
- (13-14) <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> to go to the line "You skilled"
- (15-16) <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> to go at the beginning of the word "skilled"
- (17) <kbd>x</kbd> to delete the "s"
- (18-19) <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> to go on the end of "my" to be just up to the *Y* of "DYE"
- (20) <kbd>j</kbd> to be on the Y of *DYE*
- (21-22) <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to change the *Y* in *I*
- (23) <kbd>j</kbd> to go to the final line to delete... and no more keystroke to spent!
- (24) <kbd>^</kbd> to be just before the word *Stop* on the closing curly brackets *}*
- (25) <kbd>l</kbd> to be on at the beginning of the word *Stop*

[image: End of level 6, keylocked]

I need one extra movs to finish it : <kbd>D</kbd> but I can't figure out how to save up this moves before.

### Actual keyboard

On the picture below are the actual keys I'm allowed to use.

[image: Actual keyboard]

### Leads

- Maybe I forgot to release somewhere the function to use the numbers and do something like <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> but I did't find it.
- There is two keys I didn't used : <kbd>~</kbd> and <kbd>X</kbd> but can't see how they should be useful here

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it finaly!

I discovered that it's possible do delete backward WORDS with <kbd>dB</kbd>. This replace my move (7). This game is really fantastic because it let my discover new moves.

Then my moves are :

- (1) <kbd>E</kbd> to move to the "!",
- (2) <kbd>l</kbd> to go to the blank character
- (3) <kbd>D</kbd> to delete the end of the line
- (4-6) <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> to be on the line "Mrs." on the "I" of  Inigo. For the moment I don't have the right to use <kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.
- (7-8) <kbd>dB</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to delete the word "Mrs. "
- (9) <kbd>j</kbd> to go the the next line
- (10-11) <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> to delete the line
- (12-13) <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> to go to the line "You skilled"
- (14-15) <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> to go at the beginning of the word "skilled"
- (16) <kbd>x</kbd> to delete the "s"
- (17-18) <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> to go on the end of "my" to be just up to the *Y* of "DYE"
- (19) <kbd>j</kbd> to be on the Y of *DYE*
- (20-21) <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to change the *Y* in *I*
- (22) <kbd>j</kbd> to go to the final line to delete... and no more keystroke to spent!
- (23) <kbd>^</kbd> to be just before the word *Stop* on the closing curly brackets *}*
- (24) <kbd>l</kbd> to be on at the beginning of the word *Stop*

Answer (score 3):

It's even possible to do it in 22 keystokes

E l D jjj dB j dd ww x jj b D B l rI

Answer (score 1):

An alternate answer is on move (23) W .

This will line wrap to the next word. placing the crusor on { of the last line.